# Honda XRV 750 1994 | Africa twin | empty tank

Tags: honda

I mistakenly put diesel into my Africa twin, XRV 750 1994. It should have now 10 liters gas and 13 liters diesel.

What's the quickest way to empty the tank?
Do recommend siphoning?
Is there a valve I can use to drain the tank?

What's your advice?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: You might get more out by siphoning than by draining, because typically the gravity output is raised a little above the base of the tank, to protect against sludge and debris finding its way to the fuel system. Good luck with that - siphoning petroleum is bad enough.